# Cron says "errors in crontab file, cannot install"

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I'm attempting to execute the following series of commands to create backups of MySQL databases.

When I attempt to add the command to my crontab using `crontab -e` I get the error "errors in crontab file, cannot install" and asks me if I want to retry.

```
mkdir /home/mysql-backup/`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`; mysql -s -r -e 'show databases' | while read db; do mysqldump $db -r /home/mysql-backup/`date '+%m-%d-%Y'`/${db}.sql; done; rm -r -f `date --date="1 week ago" +%m-%d-%Y`; du -k |sort -n > output; mail -s "MySQL Backups" "steven@brightbear.net" < output
```

Is there anything I should be changing in this file? Or should I look into creating a script file and calling that from cron.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: Definitely break that out into a script, you don't have any error checking or handling. It works now, but when it dies you'd likely want to know *why* it died.

Comment: Are you specifying how often it should be done? ie `1 2 * * * command args`?

Answer (score 6):

If you gave that script to `crontab -e` of course it will disagree.  A line in a crontab file should start with 5 fields indicating when you want the script to run, as [can be read in crontab's manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/).

On the other hand, most Linux distros nowadays have preset facilities for things that should be executed hourly (/etc/cron.hourly), daily (/etc/cron.daily), etc.  It's a whole lot easier to just put your script in a file in the appropriate directory and it will get executed in the selected time raster.  An added advantage is that in these files you won't be forced to cram everything into one line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; as a matter of style, if nothing else, I encourage to put the SQL commands into a shell script, and then run the shell script from `cron`.  (And, as Anew points out, the command sequence is easier to maintain/debug if it’s broken out into multiple lines, with comments.)  But –– is that all of what you’re feeding into `crontab`?  Look at `man crontab` and add the fields that specify when you want the command to run.

Answer (score 0):

From the [crontab(5)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab+5) man page, it looks like percent signs (%) have a special meaning, so that is probably where you're running into trouble.

Yes, you should put your commands into a separate shell script and just call that from the crontab line. This will also make it much easier to read the crontab file, and you can format your script nicely so that it's easier to maintain. And you can test it separately from the crontab that way.